# Python: how does Pickle work with defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, defaultdict

I am new to Python and am playing with Pickle and don't understand how this works

I define a defaultdict, write it to pickle. Then in a different script I read it and it still behaves like a defaultdict even without importing collections

script1:

```
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(list)

x['a'].append(1)
print(x)

with open('pick','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump( x, f )
```

script2:

```
import pickle

with open('pick','rb') as f:
    x = pickle.load( f )

x['b'].append(2)
print(x)

y = dict()

try:
    y['b'].append(2)
    print(y)
except KeyError:
    print("Can't append to y")
```

running:

```
$ python3 pick2.py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1], 'b': [2]}) 
Can't append to y
```

So, the 2nd script doesn't import defaultdict but the pickled x still acts like one. I'm confused :)

How does this work in Python? Thanks for any info :)

Comment: Does anyone know? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you look at the [pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#relationship-to-other-python-modules), specifically:

> pickle can save and restore class instances transparently, however the class definition must be importable and live in the same module as when the object was stored

So what this is telling us is that pickle will import the module that defines the object you are unpickling.

We can show this with a small example, consider the following folder structure:

```
parent/
|-- a.py
|-- sub/
```

`sub` is an empty sub-folder
`a.py` holds an example class

```
# a.py
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 'This is a string'
```

Now starting the `python` console in the `parent` directory:

```
alex@toaster:parent$ python3
>>> import pickle
>>> from a import ExampleClass
>>> x = ExampleClass()
>>> x.var
'This is a string'
>>> with open('eg.p', 'wb') as f:
...     pickle.dump(x, f)
```

Exit the shell. Move to the `sub` directory and try to load the pickled `ExampleClass` object.

```
alex@toaster:sub$ python3
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('../eg.p', 'rb') as f:
...     x = pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

We get a `ModuleNotFoundError` as pickle cannot load the class definition from the module `a` (it's in a different directory). In your case, python can load the `collections.defaultdict` class as this module is on the `PYTHONPATH`. However, to continue to use the module(s) imported by pickle you will still need to import them yourself; eg you want to create another `defaultdict` in `script2.py`.

To find out more about modules look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), specifically [6.1.2 The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: thank you! Makes perfect sense. Pickle is a bit sneaky but thank you for explaining it :)